# Adding JQuery to content loaded with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I just learned that you can use `live()` instead of `bind()` to make sure an event handler still exists after content is reloaded with AJAX... but what can I do with other added JQuery, such as `.sortable()`? I have a UL that I need to reload after sorting or adding; but after the AJAX reload, the sorting doesn't quite work right...

It doesn't completely lose the sortability, but the dragging become much more difficult; it will jump around and seemingly switch 2 other sections that's not the one I'm trying to drag. This only happens after the partial reload; my guess is that when it reloads, I need to re-attach the sortable... how can I do this? Here's my code:

```
$("#sections").sortable({
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    startIndex = ui.item.index();
                },
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Form/sortSections",
                        data: {
                            formID: '@(Model.formID)',
                            displayOrder: ui.item.index() + 1,
                            sectionID: $(ui.item).attr("id"),
                            startDisplayOrder: startIndex + 1
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $.get("/Form/_AllSections/@(Model.formID)", function (data) {
                                $("#sections").html(data);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (req, status, error) {
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `load` event with `live()` so that it runs every time the element is added to the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event

Comment: While starting to implement your solution, I found the actual problem... my AJAX get was returning the entire UL, not only the list items. So I was then adding that UL to the #sections UL... which makes for invalid HTML in more than one way. The invalid HTML must have screwed with the #draggable. Thanks for the advice; I'm sure I'll need to use `.live('load', function())` in the future.